# Button up your shirt

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> "Button up your shirt"

What is the antonym of button up?

Is it button down?

Before taking off a shirt. We need to button ___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "button up" a shirt implies that you start from the bottom button and work your way up.  You can just say "*button* your shirt" and leave to the listener to decide how they prefer to do it.

A *button-down* shirt is one with an extra button for the collar.

[image: button-down shirt]

This doesn't mean you start from the collar and work your way down (unless you want to).  Rather the term "button-down" is likely [short for "*buttoned*-down" meaning "securely fastened with a button"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160869/where-does-the-word-button-down-come-from).

The opposite of *to button* is, fortunately, *to unbutton*.  Yes, it's one of those rare cases where English makes sense; however, you do not "unbutton *down*" a shirt.  You just *unbutton* it.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You would say:

> Unbutton your shirt.

The *up* in "Button (up) your shirt" can be optional, though.

A *button-down* shirt is a shirt that can be buttoned (up). It has nothing to do with the current state of buttoning activity.

Answer (score 0):

It would be 'unbutton your shirt' this is the way that is used generally.

Comment: Please support your answer with more details.