# Do “not buttoned” and “unbuttoned” mean the same?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

A chat bot says "**Your dress is not done up**" suggests that the dress has not been fastened or closed properly, and "**your dress is undone**" simply means that the dress is not fastened or closed.

Is that correct?

Similarly, we also have these pairs

"Your shirt is not **buttoned** (or) **buttoned up**" vs "Your shirt is **unbuttoned**"

"Your jacket is not **zipped** (or) **zipped up**" vs "Your jacket is **unzipped**."

"Your shoe is not **laced** (or) **laced up**" vs "Your shoe is **unlaced**"

"Your belt is not **buckled** (or) **buckled up**" vs "Your belt is **unbuckled**"

"Your bag is not **tied** (or) **tied up**" vs "Your bag is **untied**."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button up your shirt](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142818/button-up-your-shirt)

Comment: I might say that an 'unbuttoned' shirt or dress was previously buttoned up, and has been undone by the wearer, while a shirt or dress that was 'not buttoned' has just been put on and not yet buttoned.

Comment: Usually by the wearer...

Comment: "Your fly is undone" refers to it not being done up. It may have been left undone when dressing, or it may have been left undone after opening it for its intended purpose. "Your fly is not done up" has exactly the same meaning.

Comment: "your shirt is not buttoned" and "your shirt is not buttoned up" do not mean the same. "button up" is a specific phrasal verb meaning to do the buttons up. "your shirt is not buttoned" is more likely to mean it doesn't have buttons. The same applies (even more so) to zipped / zipped up and laced / laced up.

Comment: @Peter - _your flag is flying at half-mast_, people used to say.

Comment: @timchessish - I would not regard 'your shirt is not buttoned' to mean 'your shirt does not have buttons'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I've also been told *you're flying low*.

Comment: @timchessish, I have not encountered (in Australia) "buttoned" used in the way you are suggesting. "Buttonless" would be better understood for a shirt with no buttons.

Comment: My interpretation was based on my experience of British English. Australian English may be different in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In direct answer to your question, yes - "unbuttoned" and "not buttoned" mean the same thing.

I can understand the confusion the prefix '-un' often means a reversal of something, and '*undone*' often means that something which was done has been reversed (eg "*you've undone all my good work!*".

However, the same prefix can denote that something has not been done at all - for example '*uncooked*' means that something is raw, never cooked.

When it comes to buttons on clothing, we use "button up" and "unbutton" in various ways to mean either *all* of the buttons, or just some. We might "unbutton our collar", meaning the top button of a shirt, or say "your buttons are coming undone" if one or two have worked themselves loose.

Answer (score 0):

“Your shirt is not buttoned” to me sounds like it has no buttons, maybe a zip instead.
I would use “your shirt is unbuttoned” if the buttons are not done up.

Comment: No, *your shirt is unbuttoned* is perfectly normal usage.  *Your shirt has no buttons* would be used in the case of no buttons being fitted.

Comment: "Your shirt has no buttons" may be more unambiguous to mean having no buttons but I agree with this answer with repsect to the meaning of “Your shirt is not buttoned”, certainly in British English.